# Is there any way in eclipse by which we can (ctrl+click) on a class attribute in jsp file and get the desired css definition which is linked with it?

Tags: css, eclipse, class, jsp, attributes

Index.jsp
here if we CTRL + click on class top-menu then it will show me the style.css class which has the definition for top-menu class

```
<div class="top-menu">
<!-- some things here -->
</div>
```

style.css

```
.top-menu 
{
margin : 10px;
position : relative;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, that functionality has not been implemented. In WTP, doing so for HTML would also provide it for JSPs. Interested contributers can check https://git.eclipse.org/c/sourceediting/webtools.sourceediting.git/tree/CONTRIBUTING.md for instructions on contributing a patch.